# How to properly refactor case-based nested loop?

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, refactoring

I have 4 nested loops that used based on the case given. The code is quite similar but there is a little difference in the comparison. Please check this code:

If Case 1:

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   for (j = 0; j < length; j++) {
      if (array[i][j] == array[i][j+1])
      // do something
   }
}
```

If Case 2:

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   for (j = 4; j > 0; j--) {
      if (array[i][j] == array[i][j-1])
      // do something
   }
}
```

If Case 3:

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   for (j = 0; j < length; j++) {
      if (array[i][j] == array[i+1][j])
      // do something
   }
}
```

If Case 4:

```
for (i = 4; i > 0; i--) {
   for (j = 0; j < length; j++) {
      if (array[i][j] == array[i-1][j])
      // do something
   }
}
```

As you can see that the decrement and increment are different too. It is quite hard for me to figure out how to refactor this. They have similar code behavior (duplication) but they have different conditions in the `for` and `if` statement on each case.

Comment: Case 4 is a no-op: `i` starts and ends at `0`

Comment: @StriplingWarrior my bad, fixed case 2 and 4

Comment: Is `4` a magic constant representing one less than the length of your array?

Comment: This will be really hard to answer without knowing a lot more about your program. Does the "do something" change the array or access other parts of the array based on `i` and `j`? What are your performance requirements? What's the bigger picture? Are the loops called one after the other? How important it is for `i` and `j` to go in a specific *direction* as opposed to just making sure they hit all the right values?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior no, it's a specific number used on the `//do something` part. My real code for this is quite messy. I worried that it is even hard to understand for others.

Comment: There's also a difference in the array access, e.g. `array[i][j+1]` for case 1, versus `array[i-1][j]` for case 4. That leaves little hope for a clean solution that combines all four cases into one. So the best you can hope for is to put `// do something` into a function so that you don't need to repeat `// do something` four times.

Comment: The best advice I can give is to think of why it's hard to understand for others, and whether that's because it's inherently complicated or just because the code is hairy. Try to make the code reflect how you'd explain the problem to another developer. Use classes, methods, and variables whose names explain what you're doing. Once you do that, it might become clear how these loops relate to one another and can be refactored. Or you might find the loops disappear entirely: maybe an array isn't even the data structure you need to represent what you're trying to represent in your code.